# Build something like Twitter's SpiderDuck to fetch URLs real-time?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, fetch, react-redux

I'm in the initial steps of building a website and I would like to know if it's realistic for 1-2 people to build a real-time URL fetcher style Twitter/FB?

Let's say I submit a post with a link, I want the fetcher to add a summary from the link and the main picture to the 'post'.

I'm working with react-redux for client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how much time/money you want to invest.
Being very blunt, it's not worth it - even Twitter/FB have trouble with it sometimes, and building a parser that works correctly on every single page would be almost impossible (think SPA).

You'd be better off using a third party solution - there are a few out there.